# Sign a Pdf using custom digital signature in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature

I've created a digital signature using Sun's code:http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/examples/GenSig.java. How can I sign a pdf file using this digital signature? That is: how can I add the signature to a pdf file?

Comment: java sign pdf - use these keywords to search here on StackOverflow or with Google and you'll get plenty of answers.

Comment: None of them consists of my question's answer. Please read question carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've taken the wrong approach. You can't easily append the signature to the PDF. PDF specification includes support for digital signatures. Those signatures are embedded into the document, and their calculation is a non-trivial process.

Your best bet is to drop your current implementation and take eg. iText library or our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-pdf.php) which will do the job for you.

If your task is to implement signature yourself, then take PDF specification, read it and implement the corresponding pieces of it (and in this case your question is way too broad to be answered in StackOverflow format).

Answer (score 0):

Steps involved in Adding Digital Signature to a PDF File:

**(I) Create Template PDFDocument :**

Create PDFDocument with template signature:
PDSignature pdSignature, 
pdSignature.setByteRange(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0});
pdSignature.setContents(new byte[n*1024]);

where n is an integer, ie multiple of kbs.

Note: Content Size should be greater than or equal to sum of length of Signature and Certificate File.

**(II) Update the Template PDF Docuement :**

**(a) Update /ByteRange[a b c d]:**
(i)    a= Offset of % in "%PDF"(=0, by default)
(ii)   b= Offset of < in "/Contents<000...000>"
(iii)  c= Offset of > in "/Contents<000...000>"
(iv)   d= Offset of F in "%%EOF"-c

**(b) update xref section:**
update the cross-reference table(xref section), that specifies the position   of the objects and

**(c) Update startxref section:**
update startxref, which is the  offset of start of cross-reference table(xref).

**(III) Generate Digital Signature of the Updated Template Document:**
Generate of the Updated Template Document Excluding the Signed Data ("000...000) of "/Contents<000...000>"

**(IV) Update Content<> Section:**
Substitute First/Initial "0"s of Signed Data length in "/Contents<000...000>" with Signed Data (Enveloped) of template PDFFile.

Suggestions:

Use SignatureInterface of PDFBox :

(a) implement SignatureInterface to call sign() method
(b) supply the input, output files, keystore, alias, pin
(c) do save incrment

(or) use any java pdf library (like iText...)

(or) Implement the Steps I-IV in java yourself.

Comment: Please, don't post the identical answer so many times; this answer is the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22299211/1729265) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216256/1729265). You might want to add a comment to the question referencing your original answer.