# Java - Best approach to Sign document using Digital Signature in Application Server

Tags: java, digital-signature

Programming language: Java

Application Server: wildfy 8

OS: Windows

Most often application will have provision to sign and upload the document from client machine ( end user who is having the soft or hard token), but i have a different case like need to sign all the document available in file directory of  backend application server. While try to sign the document using the hard token, system will prompt for password which need a manual assistance at this time, so how can we automate the password inputting in application server since its a part of business process.

If any has the solution to address please share and also suggest on which type of token we can go with like soft or hard token?

What's the best practice of signing the documents using digital token at backend server ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514638/sign-a-pdf-using-custom-digital-signature-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @MarcGiroux , i have a java code to sign the documents but the key problem is system prompt for password to sign the document, so am looking for best way to sign the documents at server side